# What the fastest way to find all points near a ray?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a bunch of 3D points (x, y, z) and a ray (origin, direction). I'm looking for the fastest way to find all points that are less than a certain distance from the ray.

Best so far is O(n) algorithm of iterating through each point, but I'm hoping there is something better maybe using a Kd-tree. Although not sure how to use that to query points near a ray as opposed to another point.

EDIT: If I put my points in an octree and then only test points in the octree voxels that the ray intersects that should be a lot faster. But is there even faster way?

Comment: The optimal data structure depends on the distribution of the points and the query rays. What can you say about them?

Comment: can you preprocess the points without it affecting your query complexity? Otherwise you will always need n iterations since you need to visit every point.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I'd say that the points and query rays are uniformly distributed.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez Yes!

Comment: In that case I would try a sparse grid with cell size equal to the *certain distance* you are querying.

Comment: Beware that if the radius is small compared to the size of the domain, the grid will be huge. Space and initialization time can become problematic. And you may travel many empty cells. Octree would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

First "inflate" your points to spheres with a radius equal to the distance in question. This reduces your query to a simple object-ray intersection query -- put these spheres into a spatial subdivision structure (octree, k-d tree, whatever) and simply query it for ray intersection. The spheres that the ray intersects correspond to the points that are at a distance less than the radius of the sphere (i.e. the given distance) from the ray.

For the spatial subdivision structure, I would definitely recommend looking into using a [Bounding Volume Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) (BVH) like an AABB tree or a sphere tree with your spheres as leaves; they are much more compact than most fixed spatial subdivision structures and are pretty easy to implement. However, any spatial subdivision method should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @eviltak, a hierarchy of bounding spheres could be a good option.

Spheres have the nice advantage to be isotropic, and when you look in the direction of the ray (with an orthogonal projection), the tree will project to a hierarchy of disks and the ray to another disk, a 2D problem. (Of course you only perform the projections on-demand.)

In this case, there is no real benefit to inflate the points, because the point-in-circle and circle-overlap tests are not significantly different.